# Inject dependencies which map to settings locator

Tags: dependency-injection, settings

At the moment, the application I work on relies on an `ISettingsService` which is injected via the constructor; classic dependency injection. As time goes and the application's capabilities (understand complexities) build-up, the quantity and diversity of the settings exposed by the service have grown.

Some classes require `ISettingsService` to access just one out of dozens of settings, and it feels wrong. In order to resolve this, I am considering to create sub entities which would map subsets of settings, for example `IDisplaySettingsService`, which would map to the relevant properties of `ISettingsService`.

What are the reasons I should or should not do this? On one hand it seems that the dependency is more targeted, but it also feels that the mapper is just hiding a greater dependency: `IDisplaySettingsService` requires `ISettingsService` to be injected. So, am I truly solving a problem here?

My situation is similar to [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/106850/injecting-properties-settings-into-an-application), but the angle of the question and the answers are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

> What are the reasons I should or should not do this? On one hand it seems that the dependency is more targeted, but it also feels that the mapper is just hiding a greater dependency

The primary reason for splitting an interface like that is because it makes things easier for you and your team in a concrete, tangible way.

On the one hand, the more targeted dependency could mean it becomes easier to write tests, because there is less set-up code to write to wire up the part you want to test.

On the other hand, if you now get components that depend on both `IDisplaySettingsService` and `IFooSettingService` and `IBarSettingService` then you may have gone overboard and made it harder to maintain the code.

> I am considering to create sub entities which would map subsets of settings, for example `IDisplaySettingsService`, which would map to the relevant properties of `ISettingsService`.

An actual mapper class is probably adding a bit too much complexity for retrieving settings. What might work better is a structure like this

```
interface IDisplaySettingsService {
  // Methods for accessing display-related settings
}

interface IFooSettingsService {
  // Methods for accessing foo-related settings
}

interface IBarSettingsService {
  // Methods for accessing bar-related settings
}

interface ISettingsService extends IDisplaySettingsService, IFooSettingsService, IBarSettingsService {
}
```

This way, each component can either declare a narrow dependency (on `IFooSettingsService` for example) or a broad dependency (on `ISettingsService`) and all those dependencies can be resolved with a single implementation of `ISettingsService`.

Comment: Thanks! I am a .Net person. By extending, are you suggesting that `ISettingsService` "inherits" the sub-services, so that there in fact is no additional implementation (mapping), but rather just a filtering mechanism through interfaces?

Comment: @Ama, yes, that is the idea I wanted to express.